# Drag and drop PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, drag-n-drop, qpushbutton

Я пишу приложение, в котором мне необходимо дать возможность пользователю перетаскивать виджеты с одних виджетов/лейаутов, на другие. 
Для того чтобы разобраться в том как это делается я написал небольшую тестовую программу.

Когда я перетаскиваю кнопки внутри одного виджета - это работает, 
но если я пытаюсь перетащить кнопку с одного виджета на другой, она исчезает.

Подскажите, как реализовать перетаскивание между виджетами?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())

        dropAction = drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)

class New_Frame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, f):
        super().__init__(f)

        self.pushButton = Button()
        self.pushButton.setParent(self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 84, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText("PushButton")

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.pos()
        e.source().setParent(self)
        e.source().move(position)

        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()

class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__()

        self.setObjectName("Dialog")
        self.resize(1078, 806)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        # self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.frame = New_Frame(self)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 331, 301))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 0);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.frame.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.pushButton = Button()
        self.pushButton.setParent(self)
        # self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 84, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.frame_2 = New_Frame(self)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 360, 331, 301))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.frame_2.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.retranslateUi(self)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))


class New_dialog(Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.pos()
        e.source().setParent(self)
        e.source().move(position)

        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    # Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = New_dialog()
    # ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: S. Nick
Простите если я вас чем то обидел, такой цели у меня не было. Я прочитал ваши ответы и воспользовался полученной информацией. Спасибо за вашу помощь.  Как видите с каждый разом мои вопросы находятся на более глубоком уровне работы с QT, это потому что благодаря помощи сообщества, продвигаюсь в написании своего приложения, и сталкиваюсь с более комплексными проблемами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `show()`  в методах `dropEvent()`.

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())
        dropAction = drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)


class New_Frame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, new, parent):
        super(New_Frame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pushButton = Button()
        self.pushButton.setParent(self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 84, 35))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText(f"PushButton \n{new}")

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.pos()
        e.source().setParent(self)
        e.source().move(position)
# +++        
        e.source().show()                                                 # +++

        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()

#class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
#    def __init__(self):
#        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__()

class Ui_Dialog(object):                                                 # +++
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):                                           # +++
    
        self.setObjectName("Dialog")
        self.resize(1078, 806)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        
        self.frame = New_Frame('frame', self)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 331, 301))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("#frame {background-color: rgb(85, 170, 0);}")
        self.frame.setAcceptDrops(True)
        
        self.pushButton = Button()
        self.pushButton.setParent(self)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
# ???        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.frame_2 = New_Frame('frame_2', self)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 360, 331, 301))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.frame_2.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.retranslateUi(self)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton\nUi_Dialog"))


#class New_dialog(Ui_Dialog):
class NewDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.pos()
        e.source().setParent(self)
        e.source().move(position)
# +++
        e.source().show()                                            # +++

        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = NewDialog()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я всегда делаю новый класс, просто в данном случае я решил сделать всё в одном файле что бы была возможность переслать код сюда. Огромное спасибо за вашу помощь